# File path error in R

Tags: r, escaping, character

I am using Rstudio (windows) and trying to get the string 'E:\Yun'. In order to avoid the "escaping character problem", I wrote the following code:

```
filename <- 'E:\\Yun'
```

However the output appears to be

```
[1] "E:\\Yun"
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a display error in Rstudio. I tried nchar(filename) and got 7 instead of 6, which indicates that the actual string may be 'E:\Yun' instead of 'E:\\Yun'.

Comment: Something like `filename <- file.path('E:','Yun')` is safer. Also, the first \ is R's way of escaping the second \. Basically, that's how R reads Windows paths.